# How to set Visual studio code as external editor for Godot in Ubuntu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04, godot, snapcraft

When I look up the installation path for VS Code in terminal with the command "which code", I get "snap/bin/code" as result. However, I can't select a file in the godot settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using snap packages, from what I know these don't have a .sh or program file laying around as normal installs have.

However if you add the /snap/bin/code path you mentioned it will work. I added it at the editor sub menu and not the bottom menu "Mono"(even though I am using C#), See picture.

[image: MenuAndSub]

As I mentioned snap packages work a bit different than normal install. I recently moved to Linux for programming etc, so I can't explain a lot about it. But this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035127/cannot-modify-files-installed-by-snap) goes into it if you want to know.

Snap packages also can't be added to favorites as you are used to. If you are looking for a way to add snap package programs to favorites or desktop view this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910821/programs-installed-via-snap-not-showing-up-in-launcher#989485). It goes into linking folders.

Hope this helps.